# Executing validation on dynamically created form fields in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm working on some legacy code that uses a `.js` file to handle client side javascript. On the form, the user is able to create fields on the fly by clicking the plus and minus buttons:

[image]

I am doing this with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{  
    var html = "<div class='registration_box01' id='showme'> <div class='title'> <h4>Additional Guest<br /></h4> </div> <div class='content'> <div class='clr'></div> <div class='label01'>*First name:</div> <div class='field01'> <input name='add_fname[]' type='text' size='40' style='min-width:250px;' /> </div> <div class='clr'></div> <div class='label01'>*Last name:</div> <div class='field01'> <input name='add_lname[]' type='text' size='40' style='min-width:250px;' /> </div> <div class='clr'></div> <div class='label01'>*Email:</div> <div class='field01'> <input name='add_email[]' type='text' size='40' style='min-width:250px;'> </div> </div> </div>";
    $(function() {
      $("#inc").click(function() { 
        var num = $(":text[name='qty']").val(function(i, v) { 
                       return Number(v) + 1;
                  }).val();
        $(this).addClass ('c' + num);
        var incrementVar = num;
        $('.additional').append(html);
      }); 

      $("#dec").click(function() {              
        $(":text[name='qty']").val(function(i, v) { 
        $("#showme").remove();
            if(Number(v) > 1){                                              
                return Number(v) - 1; 
            }
            else{    
                return 1;
            }
        });
      });  
    });
});
```

My question is how to validate the dynamic fields in Javascript? I guess I would not be opposed to adding a function in jQuery to check them.  My current function to validate the form:

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0jYr5bwX)

HTML:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateFrm(this);">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like an easy way to do this is to give each input a certain class. So for example, the "First Name" textboxes should have the class "fname-textbox". In your validation function, you know that all "First Name" textboxes should not be empty, and maybe should be at least 2 characters long (or whatever). So you could do something like this:

```
function validateFrm(form) {
    var isValid = true;
    var $form = $(form);
    $form.find(".fname-textbox").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $this_val = $this.val();
        if (isNaN($this_val) && $this_val.length > 1) {
            $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");  // won't fail if it doesn't have the class already
            // Remove any other indications of error for this field (like a "*" next to it)
        } else {
            isValid = false;
            $(this).addClass("input-validation-error");  // maybe input-validation-error has a red border and red text color?
            // Maybe add another indication of error for this field (like a "*" next to it)
        }
    });
    // And continue the validation for your other fields
    return isValid;
}
```